# Elements cut off from saved image if `bbox_to_anchor` is specified

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Consider a simple scenario:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1], [0,1], label = 'Line')

lgd = fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, -1, 1., 0), loc='lower left')
fig.savefig('figure.png', bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')
```

This saves the figure and `bbox_extra_artists` allows for more space at the bottom, but the legend is not printed.
This only happens if I try to specify values outside `[0,1]` in `bbox_to_anchor`, for example if I want the legend on the upper right side.

Any tips on why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something strange is going on with the `"tight"` calculation. The underlying cause of this is not yet clear as seen from https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10194.

For the moment you can create an axes legend, and position it in figure coordinates,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1], [0,1], label = 'Line')

lgd = ax.legend(loc='lower left', 
                bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, -1, 1., 0),  bbox_transform=fig.transFigure)
fig.savefig('figure.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: Well that is disappointing, thanks for pointing it out though. The issue with an axis legend is that the axis frame would overlap the legend in my actual scenario. I will try to find a workaround.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Note that in the example above, the legend is *exactly* at the position where you define it and where it would be expected to show up. The only problem with using an axes legend would be if you had several subplots and wanted the figure legend to show all of their labels in a single legend. If that is the case, you would need to loop over all axes and collect the handles and labels, then supply them to the legend.

Comment: I do that already, what I mean is that the `zorder` of the axis frame is somewhat always prioritised against the legend one. So I get the legend, and then the plot on top of it. I could move it out of the way of course, but that does happen (unless I'm doing something really stupid - highly likely). -- EDIT: nevermind, I was doing exactly that:something stupid ;-)